# Reduce the time for notifications

Tags: google-chrome, notification, gnome-shell

I have always liked the feature of push notifications, you get a quick notice and then it goes away into hiding(some area from where you can see it later), but ever since chrome has started giving push notification it has become a huge hassle because the notifications seem to last forever and don't go unless I remove them.

Is there some way I can reduce the time for the notification on screen because I don't want to get rid of them as they are good for quick updates but become a hassle as they don't let me do my work unless I close them

Additional Info:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with its default desktop environment(Gnome)

Here is an example notification

[image: Picture of google chrome with a notification]
The blacked out portions are simply private info(if it's not obvious)

Comment: Please mention the OS name and version and desktop environment.

Comment: You could also provide an image of a notification.

Comment: added, also this notification took about a minute to go away, I want to reduce it to only 5-7 seconds